# Using text document of whitespace containing filenames to batchcopy between directories

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, batch-processing, cp

I am using terminal in MacOS Ventura. I want to have a textile of files which I will copy using the terminal. This won't work when spaces are in the filenames.

```
A=~/Documents/test1
B=~/Documents/test2

while IFS= read -r file; do
cp "${A}/${file}" "${B}"
done < ~/Documents/testme.txt
```

Here is the example text file.

```
# contents of ~/Documents/testme.txt
the first file.pdf
the second file.pdf
the third file.pdf
```

After running the code above I get:

```
cp: /Users/userdirectoryname/Documents/test1/the first file.pdf: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/userdirectoryname/Documents/test1/the second file.pdf: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/userdirectoryname/Documents/test1/the third file.pdf: No such file or directory
```

I assume this is because of the whitespaces in the filename, but let's assume I want to use a textile with non-escaped whitespace files separated only with a line break.

How is this done?

Even when I attempt to escape the use quotes, the following errors occur.

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
cp "\"${A}/${file}"\" "\"${B}/${file}"\"
done < ~/Documents/testme.txt
cp: "/Users/userdirectoryname/Documents/test1/the first file.pdf": No such file or directory
cp: "/Users/userdirectoryname/Documents/test1/the second file.pdf": No such file or directory
cp: "/Users/userdirectoryname/Documents/test1/the third file.pdf": No such file or directory
```

Yet no trouble copy-pasting that same line!

`cp "/Users/userdirectoryname/Documents/test1/the first file.pdf" ./test2` Works!

Comment: Don't add escapes (they're just treated as part of the filename); it should work without them. I suspect there's something weird in the file or filenames (maybe nonprinting characters?). Putting `set -x` in the script before the problem command will show what the shell thinks is happening, which might help.

Comment: Your code and example filenames worked on my system with MacOS 12.6, so it's likely some oddity was lost when you tried to distill this into a question. In addition to `set -x` as suggested by @GordonDavisson, you can try adding other debug printouts to the loop, such as `typeset -p file` and `ls -l "$A"/*"$file"*`. Also, make sure you have a hash-bang (`#!/usr/bin/env zsh`) as the first line in the script to eliminate any ambiguity about which shell is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Since your variables `A` and `B` are supposed to potentially undergo tilde-expansion, the command to copy the files is

```
cp $~A/$file $~B
```